# Probability of a word being at least once in a string?

Tags: probability

Lets say I have a string of characters $S$ with length $l_S$ and a word $W$ (also a string of characters) with length $l_W$, so that $l_W\leq l_S$. Both the string and the word consist of characters of a given set $\mathbb L$. Now, what's the probability of the word $W$ being contained within the string of characters $S$ at least once? (If there are more than one occurrences in a sentence, the words may overlap)

I tried to solve this problem like so: Imagine the string of characters or sentence would look like this
$$S=\text{"fhdiucnbufgbvuabcdzsbgitvu..."}$$
and the word like this
$$W=\text{"abcd"}~.$$
If I take $l_W$ consecutive characters of $S$ the probability $P_0$ of them matching $W$ would be
$$P_0={1\over\rvert\mathbb L\rvert^{l_W}}$$
The probability $P_n$ of $W$ being contained in $S$ exactly $n$ times would be
$$P_n={1\over\rvert\mathbb L\rvert^{l_W}}\cdot\pmatrix{l_S-l_W+1\\n}~,$$
because there are $l_S-l_W+1$ locations in $S$ where $W$ could fit in.
If I add all probabilities for $1\leq n\leq l_S-l_W+1$ together I get the following
$$
\begin{align*}
P&=\sum_{n=1}^{l_S-l_W+1}{{1\over\rvert\mathbb L\rvert^{l_W}}\pmatrix{l_S-l_W+1\\n}} \\
&={1\over\rvert\mathbb L\rvert^{l_W}}\cdot\sum_{n=1}^{l_S-l_W+1}{\pmatrix{l_S-l_W+1\\n}} \\
&={1\over\rvert\mathbb L\rvert^{l_W}}\cdot2^{l_W-l_S+1}-1
\end{align*}
$$
**Would this be a valid solution?**
If $l_W=l_S$, the probability of $W$ being contained in $S$ should be $P_0$ and that's the case, but are all the other cases correct? If not, where did I make something wrong?

Comment: The formula reached at the end does not seem to work for alphabet $\{a,b\}$ and word $a$.

Comment: Seems like a DeBruijn graph (as a framework for a finite state machine) would be helpful here.

Comment: It is specific string depended. For example 11 and 01 will not have the same probability.